# Steps to Learn a Programming Language / Framework

Tags: programming-languages, frameworks

I am new to programming. I am eager to learn new programming languages / frameworks.

Can any one suggest the best way to master programming languages / frameworks?

Comment: Do you have any people around you who know more about what you want to learn than you do?

Comment: epic question. start develop some serious project but in smallest steps.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, i am just graduated from college... I am working in a mechanical related company as consultant for INTRANET portal....

Comment: There is a lot to learn, if at all possible find an experienced person physically available to you who knows what you want to learn, and ask him or her how you should approach this.

Comment: This question appears to be more polling and most, if not all, answers are equally valid. It's also incredibly broad. If you have more specific questions about things that you are learning and they are [appropriate for Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq), feel free to ask them. If you have any questions or want to contest the closure of this question, feel free to raise a question on our [Meta site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to try to find something that is a good fit for the language/framework and is something I already know how to do. That allows me to start with getting a feel for the language/framework, without the "how do I do this" and impedance mismatch between "this is what's needed but that is what's provided".

Comment: Yep Vatine... You are right... Thanks for driving me....

Answer (score 0):

There's no "best way". Best I can offer only a few recommendations to make the learning easier.

Start project with relatively fast gratification. Simple games tend to work quite well - I learned my first languages (Basic, Pascal, C) this way and ended up with published game later.

Alternatively I like also [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/). It's set of problems where you can progress in small steps towards more complex algorithms. Problems are more algorithmic and mathematical in their nature which may be off-putting for some.

Last but not least, select easier language: my choice would be Python.

Comment: Thank You MaR :) Will Take your suggestions definitely...